# How to intercept the loading of a field?

Tags: entities, hooks

I have a field called field_price.  How do I get that field on my page to display `Free` when the value is `$0.00`, and the actual value every other time?

I tried to intercept the loading of the field by doing things like:

```
mytemplate_hook_load(){
// do stuff
}

mytemplate_process_field(){
// do stuff
}

mytemplate_preprocess_field(){
// do stuff
}

etc.. etc.. etc..
```

I tried so many different permutations of the above as modules, template, changing function names etc...  But none of them ever fire.  I know I have the Field module enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

**Note: I am using drupal 7**

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i figured it out.  I put this code into my template.php of my theme:

```
function johncustom_field__field_price(&$variables) {
        if($variables['element'][0] == '$0.00') return 'Free';
        else return $variables['element'][0];
}
```

I also had to clear the cache several times before this function would fire.

Comment: Ok another problem. This code doesn't fire when a VIEW prints the field field_price.  I have to find a solution that works for views as well

Comment: Wasn't johncustom a module? [Ok thanks. let's say I have a module called johncustom.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45814/how-to-intercept-the-loading-of-a-field#comment47155_45817)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [hook_field_formatter_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) is the answer for your question. It says

> Build a renderable array for a field value.

Using above hook in a custom module you can change the field value !

For Example, if your custom module name is johncustom then your function inside module file should be

```
function johncustom_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  // Change display type & Check for your field here
  switch ($display['type']) {
    // Override check plain
    case 'taxonomy_term_reference_plain':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $element[$delta] = array(
          '#markup' => mymodule_crazy_fun_plain($item['value']),
        );
      }
    break;
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks.  let's say I have a module called johncustom.  So would my hook be called `johncustom_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display)` ?  I tried putting that in my module but it doesn't fire.

Comment: Any suggestions on why my function is not firing?  I tried putting a die() statement in the code you provided.  But it doesn't fire.  Eveyr other function/hook in my johncustom.module is firing.  I made sure I have Field UI and Field modules installed and enabled.  Is there somethign else I need to check/do?

Comment: Do this to verify , put drupal_set_message("I am in John custom module"); just above $element = array(); and go to any node view page where you are displaying fields. Check message is appearing or not !

Comment: I did as you say.  The message is not appearing on any of my pages.  ANy other ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure my module is working because I have a `function johncustom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){die('john is here');}}` .  Anytime i go to the user login, the page dies with the john is here message.  So maybe it's something very basic about drupal field that i overlooked?

Comment: @John That hook is only fired for modules implementing field formatters, you can't use it to alter other modules' implementations of a formatter